Character Text to HTML
So I have tried using jsPDF but I have tried fixing the errors but the code doesn't recognise jsPDF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Generate PDF jsPDF</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="pdf()">Create PDF</button>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function pdf() {
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        doc.text('hello, world!', 10, 10)
        doc.save('output.js')
    }
</script>

</html>

Tried changing where the function started but it still doesn't wanna play ball.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You have to use it as below:
<script>
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
    function pdf() {
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        doc.text('hello, world!', 10, 10)
        doc.save('output.js')
    }
</script>


So is it possible for instance to add text onto a pdf that currently exists using this system.

Aye anno, I was just following up the question :D

@JaromandaX so is it possible to do it ? If so could you give me some guideance please. I have a template saved on my computer I have tried referancing that pdf but I don't quite understand how to referance it so I can save text onto the pdf. I cannot see how to do this anywhere in the documentation.
